# TYPO3 9: Routing enhancers with no arguments

Tags: routes, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to use the new routing, but without using arguments. Maybe this is not supposed to work. Can someone tell me if I'm wrong?

```
routeEnhancers:
  AutoExt:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 26
    extension: AutoExt
    plugin: Widget
    routes:
      - routePath: '/create-auto'
        _controller: 'Auto::create'
      - routePath: '/change-auto'
        _controller: 'Auto::change'
    defaultController: 'Auto::create'
```

Now I'm trying to access the page with the plugin with the following URL: http://www.domain.tld/create-auto and I expected it to open the page with at least the controller Auto and action create but I always get a 404 Error.
It works with [http://www.domain.tld/index.php?id=26&tx_autoext_widget[controller]=auto&tx_autoext_widget[action]=create](http://www.domain.tld/index.php?id=26&tx_autoext_widget%5Bcontroller%5D=auto&tx_autoext_widget%5Baction%5D=create)

Comment: why dont you just create a subpages with the names create-auto, change-auto and then include something like that : - { routePath: '', _controller: 'Auto::create'}, - { routePath: '', _controller: 'Auto::change'}? This conf works for me when i have a list view and i do not want anything but the current page displayed in the url

Comment: Sorry Aristeidis, i don't get ur solution. Should i ommit the path in routePath and create subpages?

Comment: Create the subpages create-auto and change-auto. Then keep your routes how it is but remove the '/create-auto' and '/create-auto' and replace them with ''. I assume you have actions such as createAction and changeAction? If you do, create on your flexform the cooresponding swichablecontroller entry and add it on the subpages that they belong to

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. It seems like that doesn't work with typo3. I just added a dummy parameter &tx_whatever_pi1[foo]=123 and made a config like that:

```yaml
  tx_whatever_pi1:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Whatever
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/index/{foo}',  _controller: 'Pi1::index',  _arguments: { 'foo': 'foo' } }
    aspects:
      foo:
        type: WhateverAsIsMapper
```

Where the WhateverAsIsMapper looks like:

```php
class WhateverAsIsMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface
{
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        return $value !== false ? (string)$value : null;
    }

    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        return isset($value) ? (string)$value : null;
    }
}
```

Now it works with a little garbage at the end. :-/